# C# continue in one line ForEach

Tags: c#, foreach, continue

Why I can't do that ? How to manipulate code ?

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"..\DATA\data", "*.pdf").ToList().ForEach(item => item.Contains("TOPRINT") ? continue : System.IO.File.Delete(item));
```

Comment: I love easy to read code.

Comment: @MitchWheat I love one line logic puzzles ;)

Comment: Invalid expression term 'continue'

Comment: I dont like to much coding ;p

Comment: If you like logic puzzles check this ;p

Comment: `categorys.Where(c => c.Language == 0).Select(co => co.CourseList.SelectMany(p => p.PublicationList)).ToList().ForEach(item => angPublication.AddRange(item.Select(s => s.PublicationId)));`

Comment: 3 level tree to one list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add `where` before `ForEach`

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"..\DATA\data", "*.pdf")
      .Where(item => !item.Contains("TOPRINT")).ToList()
      .ForEach(f=> System.IO.File.Delete(f));
```

Answer (score 2):

Linq is designed for operating on sets of data - therefore, all queries must return a set.

You'll have to do something like this, to get a set of the required data:

```
var filesToDelete = System.IO.Directory
    .GetFiles(@"..\DATA\data", "*.pdf")
    .Where(item => !item.Contains("TOPRINT"));
```

Then operate on the data-set returned:

```
foreach(var file in filesToDelete)
    System.IO.File.Delete(file);
```

Comment: Your foreach iterates through `file` but you delete `item` :)

Comment: This is deleting all items which contain "TOPRINT", whereas the intention of the original snippet seemed to be to skip those files.

Answer (score 1):

Please, don't try doing what you tried doing, and don't do this:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"..\DATA\data", "*.pdf")
    .Where(p => p.Contains("TOPRINT"))
    .All(p => { System.IO.File.Delete(p); return true; });
```

LINQ expressions should be side-effect free. Deleting a file is surely a side effect. The `ForEach` method of `List<T>` is conceptually wrong (child of a pre-LINQ era). Transforming an array in a `List<T>` just to use the `ForEach` is doubly conceptually wrong. What I wrote at least is only "singly" conceptually wrong. (but it WILL work).

Ah... and do what Dave Bish suggested! `foreach` is the right place for side-effects!

Just remember that his `filesToDelete` will be parsed lazily, so if you enumerate it twice in two `foreach`, the `Contains` check will be done twice!

This considered, there are many powerful static methods in the `Array` class. It is a pity no one uses them.

```
var filesToDelete = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"..\DATA\data", "*.pdf");
filesToDelete = Array.FindAll(filesToDelete, p => p.Contains("TOPRINT"));

Array.ForEach(filesToDelete, System.IO.File.Delete); // or
// Array.ForEach(filesToDelete, p => System.IO.File.Delete(p));            
// or, better,  foreach (var file in filesToDelete) { System.IO.File.Delete(file); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(
    @"..\DATA\data", "*.pdf").
    ToList().
    ForEach(
        item => 
        {
            if (item.Contains("TOPRINT"))
                System.IO.File.Delete(item);
        }
    );
```

or

```
(from file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"..\DATA\data", "*.pdf")
 where file.Contains("TOPRINT")
 select file).ToList().ForEach(item => System.IO.File.Delete(item));
```